Close Sink when no messages come for 5 mins in Webflux
i have an Angular Front end and spring boot backend. I have to stream some messages from backedn to the front. I am using webflux to send messages to the front end and in the UI i am using SSE to read the events. It works fine. Below is my streaming end point
This works
@Getmapping(value ="/get/events")
public Flux<MyClass> getStreamingEvents(){

   Flux<MyClass> myflux = sinkConfig.getMysink().asFlux().cache();
   return myflux;
}

This does not work. This has stopped sending any messages to the UI
@Getmapping(value ="/get/events")
public Flux<MyClass> getStreamingEvents(){

   Flux<MyClass> myflux = sinkConfig.getMysink().asFlux().doOnNext(message -> {
       log.info("Message recived"); 
        resetTimer()
     }.doOnCancel(()->{
     log.info("Stream has been canceled")}
     .doFinally(signalType ->{
     if(signalType == SignalType.CANCEL{
       log.info("Cancelled")
      } 
      })
      .cache();
   return myflux;
}

private void resettimer(){
//code to reset timer. if timer reaches then cancel;
  cancelFlux();
}

private void cancelFlux(){
Disposable d = sinkConfig.getMysink().asFlux();
d.dispose();
}

I have two issues

once the connection is established from the browser, i see the messages flowing. But after some time, even if no messages are being sent, the cpu utilization goes crazy and the whole server hangs.

I am thinking that this is due to the fact the connection is still open. How do i make sure to close the sink if no messages are coming for like 5 mins. I can cancel the flux and dispose the connection. But my second code is not working.


